# python interactive plot newest line in color, rest in black

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, reset, interactive

I am trying to plot multiple lines in Python using `matplotlib` using `plt.waitforbuttonpress(-1)` so that I can analyse each new line separately. But when doing this I would like the newest line to have a color and the rest to be black. I know how to give a new line a color, but I can't seem to find a way to reset all previous lines to black. Is this possible? So for example:

[image: Example results]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over the old lines and set the line color, before plotting the new one with a certain color. Unfortunately `plt.waitforbuttonpress()` doesn't seem to work on my computer, but something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as pl

pl.figure()
ax=pl.subplot(111)
for i in range(10):
    # 1. set all lines to a black color
    for l in ax.get_lines():
        l.set_color('k')

    # 2. plot the latest one in a red color
    pl.plot(np.arange(10), np.random.random(10), color='r')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `line.set_color('k')` to set the colour of the line after plotting it, where `line` is a matplotlib `Line2D` instance. Luckily we can access all the lines from a `Axes` instance in the list `ax.lines`, so its just a case of looping over that list and setting all lines to black before plotting your new line. We can do that in one simple line of code:

```
[l.set_color('k') for l in ax.lines]
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.ion()

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(5)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.set_xlim(0,4)
ax.set_ylim(0,6)

ax.plot(x,y,'r-')

plt.waitforbuttonpress(-1)

[l.set_color('k') for l in ax.lines]
ax.plot(x,y+1,'r-')

plt.waitforbuttonpress(-1)

[l.set_color('k') for l in ax.lines]
ax.plot(x,y+2,'r-')

plt.waitforbuttonpress(-1)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]